# can I use facebook like button on a second page (not the index)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-apps, facebook-page

i have this app that asks the user to take a quiz and after that quiz (on the *result* page), the user has to like the page to continue using the app.

so, i need to retrieve `$_REQUEST["signed_request"]` on that page.

the problem is.. i can print `$_REQUEST["signed_request"]` only on the *index* page, but NOT on the *result* page...

and, by the way, when i click on the "like" button of the page, it redirects me on the *index* (again) instead of staying on the *result* page.. causing the user to begin the quiz again!

what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store whether or not the user has liked the page in a session variable and access it in the second page

Comment: that's good.. i'm trying this apporach.. but what about the redirection to the index when the user clicks "like"?.. is there a way to track down that action in the index page?

Comment: If they click a like button inside your iframe, track the edge.create event in javascript. If they click the like button outside your iframe, no.

Comment: no.. it's the like button of the Facebook Page Tab.. (the url is like www.facebook.com/MyPage/app_098098098098098 )